# How to divide an image into 5x8 (i.e. not of the same width and height) blocks and save all the individual images in another directory using python?

Tags: python, image

I tried dividing images in python using numpy but it always resulted in an error since it showed that the image cannot be divided if the dividing dimensions are unequal. Also I tried using image_slicer.slice, it worked but it did not give the desired result since i want the image to be divided into 5x8 blocks and imageslicer divides the image into equal parts. Kindly respond. I have attached the image as well.
Edit: Also i tried using numpy and converted the image into array and tried using hsplit and vsplit. But i think it says it can only split arrays when they are to be divided into same dimension.
The code :

## Using image_slicer

import image_slicer

image_slicer.slice('path/image.jpg', 40)

## Using crop function

path1 = "path from where image is stored"

path2 = "path where modified images have to be stored"

listing = os.listdir(path1)

for file in listing:

```
for x in range(0,600):

    for y in range(0,880):

    image = Image.open("the image")

    top = 0

    left = 110

    top = top + x

    left = 110 + x

    right = 120 + x

    bottom = top + left + right

    crop = image.crop((left,top,right,bottom))

    crop.save(path2 +  "new.jpg")

    x = x+120

    y = y+110
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kNMl.jpg)

Comment: Add a sample image here ?

Comment: please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the image as well in the hyperlink. Kindly go through it!

Comment: I think what warped means is that you show us you the code of your attempts of solving the problem.